# Node.js not forwarding to "Google Drive Login" on server, but works on localhost

Tags: javascript, node.js

On of our developers is trying to implement on Node.js to upload files with Google Drive. 
When we are running the code locally on our machines the redirect works great to Google Account Selection, where we need to select with what account we want to login on Google, and then select files.

However, where we are uploading this code on our server, and we are running the same url (with domain) 
then we are not being redirected to the Google Login.. It just get stuck on msg:okay.

Any ideas to solve this mystery and why?

Here is our code.

```
init = async () => {
    }
    googleDrive = async (req, res) => {
        const scopes = [
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata'
        ];

        const authorizeUrl = oauth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
            access_type: 'offline',
            scope: scopes,
        });
        try {
            opn(authorizeUrl, { wait: true }).then(cp => {
                console.log('cp', cp)
                const server = http
                    .createServer(async (req, res) => {
                        try {
                            if (req.url.indexOf('/google-drive/callback') > -1) {
                                const qs = new url.URL(req.url, `${process.env.SERVER_API_URL}`)
                                    .searchParams;
                                res.end(
                                    'Authentication successful! Please return to the console.'
                                );
                                server.destroy();
                                const { tokens } = await oauth2Client.getToken(qs.get('code'));
                                oauth2Client.credentials = tokens;
                                resolve(oAuth2Client);
                            }
                        } catch (e) {
                            console.log('error', e)
                            reject(e);
                        }
                    })
            });
            return res.send({ msg: 'okay' })

        } catch (e) {
            return res.status(500).send(e);
        }
    }
```

This is the **error** in our server when triggering the refresh button to run the code:

`(node:25032) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Exited with code 3
    at ChildProcess.subprocess.once.exitCode (/home/gitlab-runner/builds/sF6wSuyj/0/easynote/easynote-api/node_modules/open/index.js:122:13)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:286:20)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:448:20)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:982:16)
    at Socket.stream.socket.on (internal/child_process.js:389:11)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:448:20)
    at Pipe._handle.close (net.js:607:12)
(node:25032) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 12)`

Comment: I believe there is a hidden exception... could you replace const { tokens } = await oauth2Client.getToken(qs.get('code')); with const { tokens } = await testfunc();

And define testfunc as:

    function testfunc() {
      try {
      oauth2Client.getToken(qs.get('code'));
      catch (e) {
        console.log("testfunc", e);
      }
    }

Answer (score 0):

I add the comment as a answer, so you can check better the code changes:

I believe there is a hidden exception...

could you please replace

```
const { tokens } = await oauth2Client.getToken(qs.get('code'));
```

with:

```
const { tokens } = await testfunc();
```

And define a local testfunc as:

```
function testfunc() {
  try {
    return oauth2Client.getToken(qs.get('code'));
  } catch (e) {
    console.log("testfunc", e);
  }
}
```

Probably the Google API is discerning somewhat based on referer.

Also, check the network tab in the developer tools for suspecting request errors.